# Como alterar um formato de data brasileiro para formato americano em postgres?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, query

estou tentando alterar uma data no grafana que vem de um banco de dados PostgreSQL, a data em em formato brasileiro, mas preciso que seja em formato americano, quando tento usar a função "TO_CHAR"
Surge o seguinte erro:
[image: Erro no grafana]

O meu código é o seguinte:

```sql
SELECT
TO_CHAR(columnx, 'MM-DD-YYYY') and sum(columnx)
FROM table
WHERE $__timeFilter(columnx::date) and seguimento ='xxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

O que está acontecendo é que o tipo da coluna 'columnx' não está como data. Observe que no 'where', você tá transformando em data através do : '::date'.
Portanto, para resolver faça o seguinte:

```sql
TO_CHAR(columnx::date
```

Ficando com:

```sql
SELECT
TO_CHAR(columnx::date, 'MM-DD-YYYY') and sum(columnx)
FROM table
WHERE $__timeFilter(columnx::date) and seguimento ='xxx'
```